# Multicolored Progress Bar for WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I want to make a progress bar with multiple colors with C#. For example it would have a maximum value of 15.

1-5 Red
5-7 Blue
7-8 Color3
8-12 Color4
etc

I've looked around but haven't found a lot on this topic.

Comment: Nobody *needs* a "multicolored progress bar".  Like I always say - if you can't do it from a command line in 7-bit ASCII, then it probably isn't worth doing ;)

Comment: Have you considered using multiple single-colored bars, placed side by side? Not sure how good it would look, but it's certainly easy to implement :)

Comment: http://www.syncfusion.com/ has many different customized/customizable .Net UI controls/

Comment: Unmasking a multicolored bar would do.

Answer (score 1):

Check this article: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Red-To-Green-scale-using-an-IValueConverter.aspx
There there's an example how to calculate a color depending on numeric value and how such converter may be used to color-code the "seriousness" of the value.

Even if you are not using WPF (I hope you are), the knowledge will surely be useful to you.

Comment: I am using winforms, but i will give it a go :)
edit: not working for, me i need a progress bar with multiple colors in its different segments, but thank you anyways :P

Comment: aaw.. winforms? then changing the bar will be much harder.. It probably will be easier to write a new progressbar-ish control from scratch than to modify the PB itself.. At least you can borrow the color-calculations ;) I think that GrayFox374's post will do the trick

Comment: Links from (now deleted) GrayFox374's answer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323088/en-us + http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9564/A-Smooth-ProgressBar-for-everyone + http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9635/A-Smooth-ProgressBar-for-everyone-Part-Duex